# Merge two lists of objects in Java to create a Json with Jackson

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, jackson

I´d like to pass two List of objects retrieved from DB to my view via Ajax request. How could I wrap them in one object to serialize with Jackson and deserialize in view?

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    jsonTutorias = mapper.writeValueAsString(tutorias);
    jsonProfesores = mapper.writeValueAsString(profesores);
```

How could I manage json object in Ajax request?

```
 ... success: function (json) {
          data = JSON.parse(json);
          data.jsonTutorias[].item??
          data.jsonProfesores[].item??
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge them using `Map` class:

```
Map response = new HashMap<>();
response.put("tutorias", tutorias);
response.put("profesores", profesores);

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(map);
```

In `JavaScript`:

```
success: function (json) {
   console.log(json.tutorias);
   console.log(json.profesores)
}
```